# Save/consume body(html) response from a request.post into a global variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, request, http-post

I want to save the content of body into my global variable `returnData` so that I can return that to the outer function. But it works only when I `console.log` it inside the callback. Data is not saved into the global variable.

```
    var returnData; // This is where I want to store the output of request.post


    function getDataFromPostRequest() {
      request.post(
        {
          url: "http://example.com",
          formData: {x: "y"},
        },
        function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
          console.log(body) // this is working
          returnData = body;

        }
      );
    }

    console.log("returnData ", returnData); // This is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it:

```
var returnData; // This is where I want to store the output of request.post

function getDataFromPostRequest() {
  request.post(
    {
      url: "http://example.com",
      formData: {x: "y"},
    },
    function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
      console.log(body) // this is working
      returnData = body;
      console.log("returnData ", returnData);
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question is why is it `undefined` in the outer scope and how can we consume the `body` outside the `request.post`